# Pass Boolean value in a component call from index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, angular11

I have created a component and trying to pass boolean value inside it as @input which will help me to show/hide a div. But it is giving me undefined. can anyone please point out what is wrong in this?

Index.html

```
<abc-comp x="1" y="64" [showviewmore]="true"></abc-comp>
```

abc-comp.ts

```
  @Input() x = '';
  @Input() y = '';
  @Input() showviewmore : boolean;
```

abc-comp.html

```
  <div class="col-xs-4" *ngIf="showviewmore">
      //Some Content and tags
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try modified code below

```
<abc-comp x="1" y="64" [showviewmore]="true"></abc-comp>
```

abc-comp.tstry

```
@Input() x = '';
@Input() y = '';
@Input() showviewmore : boolean =false;
```

Comment: Hi @Divya, Thank you for posting it. I am able to pass the value. But still, ng-IF is not hiding the div even if the flag value is false. Am I making some mistake here?

Comment: @RiteshSingh  your approach was correct only you have to define default value inside comp.ts. check updated code

Comment: hi, @Divya I have tried this. Now the value is always False even if I pass True when calling the component. :(

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-7wlf3y